# docker_ is being appended when creating container

Tags: java, docker

For some reason `docker_` is being appended before repository image name. Here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    build: ./db/mysql
    volumes:
      - type: volume
      name: mysql_volume
      source: ./db/mysql/data
      target: /var/lib/mysql
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql:latest AS mysql

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MYSQL_USER=abc
ENV MYSQL_PASS=abc

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
```

Here is what `docker images` gives:

```
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker_mysql            latest              b193d171468b        13 seconds ago      547MB
mysql                   latest              9b51d9275906        3 weeks ago         547MB
```

Whenever I delete all the images along with system prune and run `docker-compose up`, 2 images are formed and `docker_` is being appeneded. I don't want interdependent images. Any pointers?

Comment: Is your `docker-compose.yml` in a folder named `docker`?

Comment: @acupajoe Yes . .

Comment: Might wanna take a look here! https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2982

Comment: Thank you . . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker-compose will use the last component of the directory containing docker-compose.yml as the project name, and add that to the image names it builds. You can run docker-compose with -p  flag to change the project name.

Comment: Is there any way I can skip that? I just don't want anything before it's image name for now.

Comment: afaik, no. That's how docker-compose tracks containers.